# Changing background colour of each tab in custom tab bar

Tags: swift

How can I change the background colour for each tab in an iOS application in Swift, as shown in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented with the help of setting images on each tab:

```
let aryTabImages = ["home-icon.png","help-icon.png","photos-icon.png","cart-icon.png","search-icon.png"]
```

Assign to each tabbar item:

```
for (index, item) in self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items!.enumerate() {
    item.image = UIImage(named: aryTabImages.objectAtIndex(index) as! String)!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    item.selectedImage = UIImage(named: aryTabImages.objectAtIndex(index) as! String)!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
}
```

Also Make sure about:

1. Tabbar item height for each IOS device
2. Tint color correctly selected of UITabbarController's tabbar.

Comment: Getting the error at : for item in self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items!  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: check you have defined tabbaritems.

Comment: hi Arvind please share me the complete class code of a tab bar which having different background colour for each tab.

Comment: Share the code, what you have done? I'll share where are the issues.